# How to display table data into datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#

```
mySqlCnnection.Open();
 string list = "select * from login";
 MySqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(list, mySqlCnnection);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dataadapter.Fill(ds, "login");
 dataGridView1.DataSource =ds.Tables[0];
```

I want to display the entire login table data in a datagridview but am getting an empty widget?some one could please?

Answer (score 1):

Call `DataBind()` after assigning the DataSource.

Comment: with what object we shall call DataBind()?

Comment: Call it on the `Page` object is best practice.

Comment: Is the code you posted on a WebForm (ie. a class inheriting `Page`) ? In that case, just call `this.DataBind()` as the final statement. If not, you could call `dataGridView1.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DataTable instead of using DataSet to fill data. Or check your sql connection.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are using this code. On which you are using it? Try it on on_load event.
Use Default view and then bind the data using DataBind() method.

dataGridView1.DataSource =ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

dataGridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
    mySqlCnnection.Open();
    string list = "select * from login";
    MySqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(list, mySqlCnnection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "login");
    dataGridView1.DataSource =ds.Tables[0];
```

And on the next line ...

```
dataGridView1.Databind();
```

Ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use binding source as datasource of your datagrid.

```
var bindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string list = "select * from login";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(list , db.connect());

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
```